# XSD for one element only

Tags: java, html, validation, jsf-2, xsd

I like to have an exception if an form-id is not given.

But this throws an Exception `Cannot find the declaration of element 'ui:composition'`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <complexType name="form">
        <attribute name="id" use="required"/>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

this is my xhtml i validate against:

```
<ui:composition template="/template/overall.xhtml" 
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
                xmlns:a4j="https://ajax4jsf.dev.java.net/ajax"                 
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
     ... <h:form id="Make_sure_i_exists"> ...
</ui:composition>
```

Regards

Comment: To validate i use maven's `xml-maven-plugin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use XSD is impossible. I did it by a unit-test (guess its a good matching usecase).

```
public class IdFullQualifiedTest extends DefaultHandler2 {
    public final static List<String> NEED_ID = Arrays.asList(new String[] {
            "h:form", "h:inputText", "h:commandButton", "a4j:include",
            "h:dataTable" });

    public void testStructure() throws ParserConfigurationException,
            SAXException, FactoryConfigurationError, IOException {
        Iterator<File> iterateFiles = FileUtils.iterateFiles(new File("src"),
                new String[] { "xhtml" }, true);
        SAXParserFactory f = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser p = f.newSAXParser();
        while (iterateFiles.hasNext()) {
            p.parse(iterateFiles.next(), this);
        }
    }

    private Locator loc;

    @Override
    public void setDocumentLocator(Locator loc) {
        this.loc = loc;
    }

    @Override
    public InputSource resolveEntity(String name, String publicId,
            String baseURI, String systemId) throws SAXException, IOException {
        return new InputSource(new StringReader(""));
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String arg0, String d, String qname,
            Attributes attrs) throws SAXException {
        int idx = NEED_ID.indexOf(qname);
        if (idx >= 0) {
            if (attrs.getIndex("id") < 0) {
                throw new SAXParseException(
                        NEED_ID.get(idx) + " has no id (" + loc.getSystemId()
                                + ":" + loc.getLineNumber() + ") .", loc);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can't find `<ui:composition>` because it wasn't declared in your schema.

If you are validating elements from the JSF schema, you have to import it:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        targetNamespace="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:import namespace="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" schemaLocation="http:// ... /jsf-facelets_2_0.xsd" />

    <complexType name="form">
        <attribute name="id" use="required"/>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

You should find the `jsf-facelets_2_0.xsd` in your implementation files or JARs.

Comment: If you want to use XSD the other option you have is to redeclare the composition element and not import anything